# Creating a custom Fragment with full screen map

Tags: android, android-fragments, mapfragment

I'd like to build a `Fragment` which consists of a full screen map overlaid with other views (A `ViewPager`, `EditText`, and the like). I've thought of two different options:

1. Create a `Fragment` with a `MapView` near the root of the layout and set it to `match_parent`, then use other `View`'s as normal.
2. Subclass `MapFragment`.

I've subclassed `MapFragment`:

```
public class ListMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Displaying this fragment works as normal and the map takes up the entire fragment. However, I would like to display various views as described above over the map. If I try to inflate and return a view (as you would with a normal `Fragment`) by instead returning a view, a NPE occurs:

```
public class ListMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_map, container, false);
        return view; 
    }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.ad.y.v()' on a null object reference

If I try calling the supers method before returning a view, the layout is loaded, but the map is not:

```
public class ListMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_map, container, false);

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }
```

Out of the two options, is one preferred over the other? And if #2 is preferred, what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're actually modifying any of `MapFragment`'s functionalities you should not be deriving from it. Just create a fragment with a `FrameLayout` and MapView as `match_parent` and add views to it.

And also that is what is wrong with the above code as well. When you derive from `MapFragment` and override its methods some of its initializations don't happen and as a result you get an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

> If I try calling the supers method before returning a view, the layout is loaded, but the map is not:

This is the way to go. But you also need to load the map.

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    // extends SupportMapFragment, but MapFragment should work as well

    View rootView;
    private MapView mapView;

    public MyMapFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);//when you already implement OnMapReadyCallback in your fragment

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mainActivity.googleMap = map;
        // play with your map
    }
}
```

XML fragment_map.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```